# Getting Error while installing Ejabberd in windows

Tags: ejabberd

I'm trying to install Ejabberd in the windows but getting the error that **Error running post install script** . I have tried version 20.04 and 20.02, in both the version I'm getting same error.

I have tried many options like

1. Install as an administrator
2. Uninstall then Goto C:\ProgramData\ejabberd\ and delete the ejabberd folder and reinstall.
3. Run postinstall.cmd file manually which is located in ejabberd\bin folder.

But none of them worked. Can anyone help me to solve this?

Error image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/46276226/84561409-b484e100-ad69-11ea-9c68-b5cc6b76c40b.PNG

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but just in case: the installers are for Windows 7 or newer. And apparently they are for 64bits versions, not for 32bits.

Comment: I'm using Windows10 64 bit version so that's not the issue.